# Python variable in class gets modifid somehow?

Tags: python, class

I don't really understand the inheritance method of python. I have a class like this, it handles a special matrix.

```
class PSSM:

    matrix = {}
    matrixfile = ""

    def __init__(self,matrixfile):
        self.matrixfile = matrixfile
        PSSM.matrix = {}
        PSSM.matrixfile = matrixfile
        try:
            f = open("%s" %matrixfile,"r")
            for i in f:
                PSSM.matrix[i.split()[0]] = []
                for j in i.split():
                    try:
                        PSSM.matrix[i.split()[0]].append(float(j))
                    except ValueError:
                        continue
            f.close()
        except IOError:
            try:
                for i in StringIO(matrixfile):
                    PSSM.matrix[i.split()[0]] = []
                    for j in i.split():
                        try:
                            PSSM.matrix[i.split()[0]].append(float(j))
                        except ValueError:
                            continue
            except ValueError:
                return

    def normalize(self):
        newmatrix = self.matrix
        for i in range(len(newmatrix["A"])):
            suma = 0
            for j in newmatrix.keys():
                suma += newmatrix[j][i]
            for j in newmatrix.keys():
                newmatrix[j][i] = newmatrix[j][i]/suma
        results = ""
        for i in newmatrix.keys():
            results += i
            for j in newmatrix[i]:
                results += "\t% 6.2f" %j
            results += "\n"
        return results
```

The program runs fine, but when I try to print out and test it I encountered some unexpected results.

I have a `printmatrix` object as well, which print the matrix (adds it into a string and returns the string).

```
#returns the matrix I used as input
print PSSM.printmatrix(a) 

# returns the normalized matrix as expected
print PSSM.normalize(a)
```

But if I run

```
print PSSM.printmatrix(a)
```

again it returns the normalized matrix.

Somehow the `matrix` variable inside the class inherits the `newmatrix` variable?

How can the `matrix` variable chance if I havent changed it anywhere?

I just copyed values form it, and only altered the `newmatrix` variable.

Answer (score 2):

```
class PSSM:
    matrix = {}
    matrixfile = ""
```

Matrix and matrixfile are not bound to an instance but to the class itself. So all instances of that class share it.
Move these to the `__init__` function:

```
def __init__(self,matrixfile):
  self.matrix = {}
  self.matrixfile = matrixfile
```

Same goes for `PSSM.matrix`, change it to `self.matrix`

Also working with OO you should create an instance of PSSM and use that.

```
myMatrixFile = "bla"
myPssm = PSSM(myMatrixFile)

print myPssm.printmatrix() #returns the matrix I used as input
print myPssm.normalize() # returns the normalized matrix as expected
```

Comment: I changed the location of "matrix = {}" but the problem is still there.

a = PSSM("locationofmatrix")
print PSSM.printmatrix(a),

print PSSM.normalize(a),

print PSSM.printmatrix(a),

The second print still prints the normalized insted of the original